# Automatic email confirmation by django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I want a user email to be automatically confirmed if the admin adds a user. Currently the admin adds a user, next select the newly created user and edit manually to confirm user email. I want this process to be automatic from the admin whenever admin creates a user.

accounts/models.py--

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from phonenumber_field.modelfields import PhoneNumberField

User._meta.get_field('email').blank = False
User._meta.get_field('email')._unique = True

class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name ='profile')
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    phone_number = PhoneNumberField( blank=True, null=True)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
        instance.profile.save()
```

accounts/admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import admin as upstream
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group, User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext, ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Profile


class ProfileInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Profile
    can_delete = False
    verbose_name_plural = 'Profile'
    fk_name = 'user'

class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = (ProfileInline, )
    list_select_related = ( 'profile', )
    list_display = ('email', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')

    #exclude = ('username',)

    fieldsets = (
        ('Personal information', {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'password')}),
        ('Permissions', {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser', 'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        ('Important dates', {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )

    add_fieldsets = (
        ('None', {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}
        ),
    )

    def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
        if not obj:
            return list()
        return super(CustomUserAdmin, self).get_inline_instances(request, obj)

    def get_ordering(self, request):
        return ['-date_joined']

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.user.email_confirmed = True
        super(CustomUserAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)


admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, CustomUserAdmin)
```

I have no clue how can I update the model profile `email_confirmed` to `True` if the user is created by admin.If not admin then `email_confirmed` is set to `False`.

Any help or suggestion is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you see `save_model` method?

Comment: @SergeyZherevchuk I have updated admin.py but the field value didn't change.

Comment: `obj` in your case - is `User` model instance. Call `super` first to make sure your profile instance already created with `post_save` signal. Then try to update `profile.email_confirmed` with `obj.profile.email_confirmed = True` and `obj.profile.save()` calls.

Comment: It seems to be working from admin end. I cannot test from user end as I am getting another error(Column Integrity) in the frontend. But thanks a lot for helping me out.

Comment: Update: It worked great from both places. Many thanks for your help.